# How to backup Windows 10 start menu layout?

Tags: windows-10, backup, start-menu

I have 3 Windows 10 devices and I wanna backup and import start menu layout on each device as Windows 10 isn't supporting layout syncing.

Most of the solutions I've found are for Windows 8 only.

One site showed me a way to export the layout by using this command:

```
Export-StartLayout -Path C:\StartLayout.XML
```

but nothing about how to import it!

I tried [steps mentioned in this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/12/23/step-by-step-windows-10-start-menu-customization-via-powershell.aspx) and both of them shows me this error

```
Export-StartLayout : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'as'
At line:1 char:20
+ export-startlayout -as bin -path c: \customstartscreenlayout.bin ?ver ...
+                    ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-StartLayout], ParameterBindingException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Windows.StartLayout.Commands.ExportStartLayoutCommand
```

This is a screenshot for everything I've tried .. https://goo.gl/Dya6ey

Comment: Import-StartLayout? have you tried this? http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/12/23/step-by-step-windows-10-start-menu-customization-via-powershell.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes i did and it shows me this error i've mentioned above

Comment: don't use this **bin**

Comment: @magicandre1981 Still the same

Comment: The parameter’s name is `-As`. It is case sensitive. Also, why don’t you try `Import-StartLayout`?

Comment: @DanielB Nothing, still the same .. i've added a screenshot above for everything i 've tried.

Comment: There is at least one typo *in every single command*. It’s really not that hard. Just type the command correctly, without spaces in the file path or question marks instead of dashes and whatnot.

Comment: @DanielB You can give me this "Typo-free" command instead all of this!!

(Case sensitive, Import-StratLayout, without **bin**, with and without spaces in the file path) I've tried all of this.
Anyway thnx for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Export-StartLayout -path "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\StartBackup.bin" –verbose

Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\StartBackup.bin" -mountpath "$env:systemdrive\"
```

[image]

But please note that [it only applies to the default profile](https://superuser.com/questions/1117136/import-startlayout-doesnt-change-anything).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the *As* parametered is only available in Windows 8.1 and 2012 R2.
Try without it, just name the file *.bin*.

```
Export-StartLayout -Path C:\StartLayout.BIN
```

Answer (score 0):

From this link: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3088-backup-restore-start-layout-windows-10-a.html

1. Back up registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount
2. Back up file %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\DefaultLayouts.xml

To restore:

1. (*Mess with registry at your own risk*) Delete registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount   (*you cannot omit this step*)
2. Merge registry key backed up in steps above.
3. Restore DefaultLayouts.xml file backed up in above steps, overwriting current %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\DefaultLayouts.xml
4. Sign out of Windows and sign back in again.