# Import-StartLayout doesn't change anything

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I'm trying to create a layout template on Windows 10 using the Export/Import-StartLayout commands.

Here's what I've done.

1. Open an admin PowerShell window.
2. Run `Export-StartLayout -Path layout.xml`.
3. Unpin some tiles from my start menu
4. Run `Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath layout.xml -MountPath C:\`

When I look at my start menu now, the tiles I remove haven't come back. The Import command gives me no errors.

Am I using the commands wrong? Is there something else I need to do before/afterwards?

Here's the contents of layout.xml

```
<LayoutModificationTemplate Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6" xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout">
        <start:Group Name="" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="C:\Users\Jozsef\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="{6D809377-6AF0-444B-8957-A3773F02200E}\NetBeans 8.0.2\bin\netbeans64.exe" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{6D809377-6AF0-444B-8957-A3773F02200E}\HeidiSQL\heidisql.exe" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" />
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="2" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.mail" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, importing the layout will only modify the default user. As such, changes wouldn’t affect existing user profiles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Import-StartLayout command only works in the default user profile. It is used for creating and deploying windows 10 system images. It does not work in the current users profile or any other already created profiles.

[Source](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/174369-windows-10-start-menu-layout-exportbackupimport/)
and prior experience.

Comment: After baging my head (hard) against the same issue, I can confirm that `Export-StartLayout + Import-StartLayout` works with the default profile only. I'm looking for an alternative: https://superuser.com/questions/1194556/backup-and-restore-windows-10-start-menu-tiles-replacing-vedatamodel-edb-no-eff

Comment: After using Import-StartLayout to set a default start menu layout in the default profile, when a new user creates a profile, and that default start menu layout is applied, can the user make further changes to the start menu layout? or is it locked and set in stone for them?

Comment: @Baodad - The user can make changes as and when they choose

Answer (score 4):

Simplest method is to use [Backup Start Menu Layout](https://www.sordum.org/downloads/?backup-start-menu-layout)

---

Another way:

Export:

1. Open an admin PowerShell window
2. Run `Export-StartLayout -Path layout.xml`

---

Import for current user:

1. Import `layout.xml` via [Group Policy](https://superuser.com/a/1194736/936934)
2. Kill `explorer.exe`
3. Start `explorer.exe`
4. Disable [Group Policy](https://superuser.com/a/1194736/936934)
5. Kill `explorer.exe`
6. Start `explorer.exe`
7. You are done :-) You now have layout imported from xml file

Without step 4 Menu Start tiles will be locked

Comment: Don't know if this is outdated but both solutions seem to not work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Some Icons didn't move, like Visual Studio, I assume they got a random GUID on Installing or something like that, but most other icons were there.

Comment: This helped me when the menu somehow duplicated an icon, and when I deleted one, it deleted both, but I was unable to add it back (it kept saying "Unpin from startmenu"...). A simple export and immediate re-import using the above worked :) Steps 2+3 & 5+6 can each be replaced with "with an explorer window open, hit restart on `Explorer` in <kbd>ctrl+shift+esc</kbd> if someone wants to stay in the GUI

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to update the current user Start layout (I am using version 1909):
I think it is similar to what is suggested by the previous answer but everything is done programmatically.
[Pete7346_solution](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2210484-current-user-start-layout)

Here is the code I have used, assuming the XML file with the layout to import resides in 'C:\StartLayout.xml'

```
$StartLayoutPath = "C:\StartLayout.xml"

Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath $StartLayoutPath -MountPath 'C:\'
New-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows -Name Explorer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" /V LockedStartLayout /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F
Reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" /V StartLayoutFile /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D $StartLayoutPath /F
Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer
Start-Sleep -s 10
#sleep is to let explorer finish restart b4 deleting reg keys
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" -Name "LockedStartLayout" -Force
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" -Name "StartLayoutFile" -Force
Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1100445)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11 there is a different solution:
[Windows 11 solution](https://medium.com/@MrNick4B/deploy-a-customized-windows-11-start-menu-8832d90b25b1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1236604)